# Unalbe to parse json Array in Android Application

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

All my Application does is..get a string from first activity and then use it in second activity to fetch download link from mysql database.

**DownloadActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.telugump3;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Query;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DownloadActivity extends Activity{
  Activity context;
   HttpPost httppost;
   StringBuffer buffer;
   HttpResponse response;
   HttpClient httpclient;
   ProgressDialog pd;
   CustomAdapter adapter;
   ListView listProduct;
   ArrayList<String> records;
   String mname;
   String sText;
   private long enqueue;
   private DownloadManager dm;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.download_activity);
   context=this;
   records=new ArrayList<String>();
   listProduct=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.product_list);
   adapter=new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.thirdlist_item,R.id.pro_name, records);
   listProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
   Intent iin= getIntent();
   Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

   if(b!=null)
   {
       mname =(String) b.getString("song_name");
       System.out.print(mname);

   }

   listProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){ 

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id){

           String sText = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pro_name)).getText().toString();

       }

   });

   BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           String action = intent.getAction();
           if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
               long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                       DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
               Query query = new Query();
               query.setFilterById(enqueue);
               Cursor c = dm.query(query);
               if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                   int columnIndex = c
                           .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                   if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                           .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                       ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                       String uriString = c
                               .getString(c
                                       .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                       view.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uriString));
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   };

   registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
           DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Request request = new Request(
            Uri.parse(sText));
    enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //create a LayoutTransition object       
      return true;
}
   public void onStart(){
   super.onStart(); 
   //execute background task
   BackTask bt=new BackTask();
   bt.execute();

   }

  //background process to make a request to server and list product information
   private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{  
   protected void onPreExecute(){
       super.onPreExecute();
       pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
       pd.setTitle("Retrieving data");
       pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
       pd.setCancelable(true);
       pd.setIndeterminate(true);
       pd.show();       

       }

       protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){ 

       InputStream is=null;
       String result="";
       try{

           records.clear();

           String query = URLEncoder.encode(mname, "utf-8");
       httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
          httppost= new HttpPost("http://necrecords.16mb.com/getsongslist.php?password="+query);
       response=httpclient.execute(httppost);         
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             is = entity.getContent();

       }catch(Exception e){

       if(pd!=null)
       pd.dismiss();  //close the dialog if error occurs 
       Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());

       }

       //convert response to string
       try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();         
            result=sb.toString();
       }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error converting result "+e.toString());

}

       //parse json data
       try{

       JSONArray jArray =new JSONArray(result);
       for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                  String record=json_data.getString("link")+"__"+json_data.getInt("test");
                  records.add(record);


          }


       }
       catch(Exception e){
       Log.e("ERROR", "Error pasting data "+e.toString());

       }

        return null;
       }   


       protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

       if(pd!=null) pd.dismiss(); //close dialog
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify the ListView to get new records

       }

       public void showDownload(View view) {
           Intent i = new Intent();
           i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
           startActivity(i);
       }

   }
}
```

logcat

```
03-23 22:20:51.423: E/IMGSRV(19723): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 37
03-23 22:20:51.423: E/IMGSRV(19723): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 38
03-23 22:20:51.423: E/IMGSRV(19723): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 38
03-23 22:20:51.423: E/IMGSRV(19723): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 38
03-23 22:20:52.133: E/IMGSRV(19734): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 37
03-23 22:20:52.133: E/IMGSRV(19734): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 38
03-23 22:20:52.133: E/IMGSRV(19734): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 38
03-23 22:20:52.133: E/IMGSRV(19734): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 38
03-23 22:20:52.313: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 51
03-23 22:20:52.343: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
03-23 22:20:52.373: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 54
03-23 22:20:52.403: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 38
03-23 22:20:52.433: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 56
03-23 22:20:52.443: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 62
03-23 22:20:52.713: E/Save(902): com.android.launcher3.Workspace$$Icicle.
03-23 22:20:52.713: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
03-23 22:20:53.243: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
03-23 22:20:53.443: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
03-23 22:20:54.413: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 51
03-23 22:20:54.823: E/lights(565): [LED] open path fail.
03-23 22:20:55.083: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 55
03-23 22:20:55.113: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 56
03-23 22:20:55.153: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 70
03-23 22:20:55.183: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 33
03-23 22:20:55.493: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
03-23 22:20:55.743: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
03-23 22:20:55.953: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
03-23 22:20:56.893: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 40
03-23 22:20:56.923: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 54
03-23 22:20:56.973: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 69
03-23 22:20:57.313: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
03-23 22:20:57.343: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 37
03-23 22:20:57.523: E/ERROR(19684): Error pasting data org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray
03-23 22:20:57.573: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 38
03-23 22:20:57.783: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
03-23 22:20:59.653: E/lights(565): [LED] open path fail.
03-23 22:21:00.033: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 40
03-23 22:21:00.043: E/IMGSRV(186): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
```

**What I'm trying to do...**

1) Since I've no idea how to convert json data to string, I've made it an array and used it in ListView. When I click the ListView I'll get the download link in the form of string.

```
String sText = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pro_name)).getText().toString();
```

Now I can use this **sText** to download required file using Android default download manager. But the ListView is not being created. Logcat shows "Cannot be converted to json array". I've used this link to fetch data. http://necrecords.16mb.com/getlink.php?password=acchata%20mucchata

Comment: can you paste your result string which you are parsing?

Comment: open the link which I've given...I'm trying to get **link** from that json code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below Code it will parse and give you the correct value.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {
                    String result = callWebService("http://necrecords.16mb.com/getlink.php?password=acchata%20mucchata");
                    JSONArray resArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i=0; i<resArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject res = resArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String link = res.getString("link");
                        String test = res.getString("test");
                        Log.v("result ==== ", link + "   ,   " + test);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                return null;
            }
        }.execute();




public String callWebService(String urlvalue) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        URL u = new URL(urlvalue);
        URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            buffer.append(inputLine);
        in.close();
        // System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        return buffer.toString();

    }
```

**Update As Per Your Code**

```
package com.example.telugump3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Query;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.xavient.kwickhelp.testappstack.R;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DownloadActivity extends Activity{
    Activity context;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    ListView listProduct;
    ArrayList<String> records;
    String mname;
    String sText;
    private long enqueue;
    private DownloadManager dm;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.download_activity);
        context=this;
        records=new ArrayList<String>();
        listProduct=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.product_list);
        adapter=new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.thirdlist_item,R.id.pro_name, records);
        listProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
        Intent iin= getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

        if(b!=null)
        {
            mname =(String) b.getString("song_name");
            System.out.print(mname);

        }

        listProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id){

                String sText = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pro_name)).getText().toString();

            }

        });

        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                            DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                    Query query = new Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                                .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                            ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                            String uriString = c
                                    .getString(c
                                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                            view.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uriString));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Request request = new Request(
                Uri.parse(sText));
        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        //create a LayoutTransition object
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        //execute background task
       new BackTask().execute();


    }

    //background process to make a request to server and list product information
    private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pd.setTitle("Retrieving data");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
            pd.setCancelable(true);
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.show();

        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){





            //parse json data
            try{

                String result = callWebService("http://necrecords.16mb.com/getlink.php?password=acchata%20mucchata");
                JSONArray jArray =new JSONArray(result);
                JSONArray resArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i=0; i<resArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject res = resArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String link = res.getString("link");
                    String test = res.getString("test");
                    String record = link+"__"+test;
                    Log.v("result ==== ", link + "   ,   " + test);
                    records.add(record);
                }



            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("ERROR", "Error pasting data "+e.toString());

            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

            if(pd!=null) pd.dismiss(); //close dialog
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify the ListView to get new records

        }

        public void showDownload(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }

    public String callWebService(String urlvalue) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        URL u = new URL(urlvalue);
        URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            buffer.append(inputLine);
        in.close();
        // System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        return buffer.toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? That was tested code working properly my side. Did you paste asynctask in OnCreat()?

Comment: In your code did you get the correct response inb result string? and change json_data.getInt("test") to json_data.getString("test")

Comment: Your code is correct it seems...I have pasted it wrong in my code...can you please change the whole code for me? please... I'll be greatful for that...

Comment: @ShahidRoshan Please check the Update As Per Your Code section. I changed your code. Just replace whole code from the Update As Per Your Code section code

Comment: Let me know if you still face the issue.

Comment: The code works now and I am able to see the ListView. But when I click the download button which executes "OnClick" method in the code...the app crashed

Comment: What's the exception? check your DownloadManager code, Try to use debugger

Comment: Found the answer sadiq bhai...just changed "String sText" in onClick method to "sText". You helped me lot bhai...thanks a lot....